# How to create dynamic links in Netlogo? - Global variables change values for agents, agents interact and then change their type accordingly

Tags: dynamic, hyperlink, netlogo, interaction

I have a system where the two global/systemic variables *economic-output-x* and *environmental-damage-y* depend on the distribution of four types of worldviews (utility-assumptions) of the agents in the model. These two state variables get distributed as internal values among all agents as income and exposure. These two marginal or individual distributed valus determine *power to persuade* (P2P) and *susceptibility for persuasion* (S4P). Each agent therefore has P2P-x and P2P-y as well as S4P-x and S4P-y.

When two agents meet (Compare [former related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22194931/netlogo-how-to-make-turtles-face-each-other-wait-3-ticks-and-then-keep-wanderi)) they exchange their internal values of P2P and S4P, which could be conceptualised as a debate, a discussion or a clash of opinions. If the substraction of these values results in a number above a particular threshold, i.e. the range between the two values is high, the 'losing' agent changes his worldview to the other one's worldview (*transition*), which in turn has an impact on the global variables.

Therefore we have quite a nested network of interrelationships and feedback loops. I am having problems putting this into practice. I have also looked at quite some opinion-influence-models but none quite grasps it the way I am approaching it.

My first attempt looked like this:

```
     ask turtles [        ; Agents are doing their thing
  [if occupied = "yes" [
    ifelse count-down > 0 
      [set count-down (count-down - 1)]
     [; get the hell out of here
       rt 180
       fd 2
       set occupied "no"
       set count-down 3] 
       ]

      if occupied = "no" [       ; Wandering around, ignoring occupied agents
     set neighbourhood other turtles in-radius 2]

     ; If someone interesting and unoccupied is near, communicate!
     set nearest-neighbour one-of neighbourhood with-min [distance myself]
     ifelse nearest-neighbour != nobody [    ; In case someone has been set as nearest-neighbour, encounter is set in motion
         if ([ occupied ] of nearest-neighbour = "no") [
            face nearest-neighbour            
            set occupied "yes"
```

> ```
>  [if ([ S4P-x ]  of self < [ P2P-x ] of nearest-neighbour) [
> ```
>
> set worldview [ worldview ] of nearest-neighbour ]

```
            ask nearest-neighbour [ 
              face myself              
              set occupied "yes"
```

> if ([ S4P-x ]  of self < [ P2P-x ] of myself) [set worldview [
>   worldview ] of myself ]

```
           ]
```

But that did not really work out. Plus, I am not quite sure whether this is the most elegant way. I doubt it. 
Is there maybe an entry on this topic on Stackoverflow which I overlooked, which is a little easier to grasp? Or another functionality in NETLOGO, which might fit my needs more appropriately?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you probably mean just `P2P-x` instead of `[P2P-x] of myself`, and I think you mean `set worldview [worldview] of myself` instead of `set worldview [worldview of myself]`. Does that fix it?

You probably don't need to use links unless you want to represent a relationship between turtles that persists over time. If the encounters between turtles are fleeting, involving links doesn't buy you anything.

I'd suggest you look at Communication T-T Example in the Code Examples section of the Models Library, and at other models where pairs of turtles meet and interact, such as PD N-Person Iterated.

Comment: If I leave the brackets for the first case, so `P2P-x` I get the error that a reporter is needed.
For the second case, he is not aware who `myself` is supposed to be, because the `face`-command comes later in the code...

Comment: Re: the error, exactly what does the code look like that is giving you that error, and what is `P2P-x` anyway, a turtle variable, or what? As for `face`, I don't really know what you mean. You're using the wrong syntax for `of`, and my suggestion uses the right syntax; so you need to take that much of my advice, at least. I'm at a loss at what further advice to give you because I don't even understand the exact intent behind the code you've provided. I don't know what agent you _want_ `myself` to refer to in the two places you've used it. What precisely are you trying to do?

Comment: It seems like you're flailing a bit which probably means you need to slow down and take smaller steps.

Comment: I tried to clean it up again. Plese let me know if that helped.

Comment: So the current code is practically impossible to read, because the indentation is so wildly inconsistent. Still, I can see that you made some fixes. Note that you can can replace `[S4P-x] of self` with just `S4P-x`; adding `[] of self` is always redundant. What question do you still have about the latest code?