# Making turtles wait x number of ticks

Tags: wait, netlogo

Part of what I am trying to do is make a breed of turtles move around, but when one reaches its destination that turtle waits for a certain number of ticks before continuing ? Also is it possible to make turtles wait for different number of ticks depending upon their destination ( different patch colors). Is it a case of making a turtle breed or global variable to count the number of ticks? The hopefully relevant code is below.

Comment: I have tried the following, but it seems to count down within 1 tick rather than a turtle staying for x number of ticks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19993631/netlogo-how-to-make-turtles-stop-for-a-set-number-of-ticks-then-continue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, this can be done by making the turtles count the number of ticks they have been on a patch. Also this has to be a turtle variable and not a global variable since each turtle will have a different value for this

The approach, I have used is this:

1. Once the turtle arrives at its destination record the `ticks` (the global variable which records the number of ticks that have passed till now) into a turtle variable say `ticks-since-here`. This works like a time-stamp.
2. On each successive tick check the difference between the current-time `ticks` global variable and the `ticks-since-here` turtle variable. If this becomes greater than the number of ticks the turtle is allowed to stay on the patch, let it choose and move to the new destination.

   breed [visitors visitor]

   ```
   globals [ number-of-visitors ]

   visitors-own [
     ; visitors own destination 
     destination
     ticks-since-here
   ]

   to go
     ask visitors [
       move
     ]
     tick
   end

   to move
     ; Instructions to move the agents around the environment go here
     ; comparing patch standing on to dest, if at dest then  choose random new dest
     ; then more forward towards new dest
     ifelse ( patch-here = destination ) 
     [
       if ticks - ticks-since-here > ticks-to-stay-on-patch patch-here
       [
         set ticks-since-here 0
         set destination one-of patches with 
         [
           pcolor = 65 or pcolor = 95 or pcolor = 125 or pcolor = 25 or pcolor = 15 or pcolor = 5
         ]
       ]
     ]
     [
       face destination
       forward 1
       if ( patch-here = destination ) 
       [
         set ticks-since-here ticks
       ]
     ]
   end

   to-report ticks-to-stay-on-patch [p]  
     if [pcolor] of p = 65
       [
         report 6
       ]
     if [pcolor] of p = 95
       [
         report 5
       ]
     if [pcolor] of p = 125
       [
         report 4
       ]
     if [pcolor] of p = 25
       [
         report 3
       ]
     if [pcolor] of p = 15
       [
         report 2
       ]
     if [pcolor] of p = 5
       [
         report 1
       ] 
   end

   to setup-people 
     ;;;; added the following lines to facilitate world view creation
     ask patches
     [
       set pcolor one-of [65 95 125 25 15 5]
     ]
     set number-of-visitors 100
     ;;;;

     create-visitors number-of-visitors 
     [
       ask visitors 
       [
         ; set the shape of the visitor to "visitor"
         set shape "person"
         ; set the color of visitor to white
         set color white
         ; give person a random xy
         setxy (random 50) (random 50)
         ; set visitors destination variable
         set destination one-of patches with 
         [
           pcolor = 65 or pcolor = 95 or pcolor = 125 or pcolor = 25 or pcolor = 15 or pcolor = 5
         ]
       ]
     ]  
   end
   ```