# How to ask turtles to wait x number of ticks?

Tags: netlogo

I want to ask if I want to ask  female to hatch after X number of ticks.
the female and male mated in March or April and give birth in January or February.

at the begining I made the code that they mate and have children in january and february

the code

```
 to-report parents-here? 
 report any? turtles-here with [gender = "male"]
     and
     any? turtles-here with [gender = "female"]
 end

to go
if ticks mod 12 <= 2 [
ask patches with [parents-here?] [
ask one-of turtles-here with [gender = "female"] [
  hatch 1 [
    set gender one-of ["male" "female"]
   ]
 ]
]
tick
```

end

but how can I ask them if parents here now so after exact number of ticks this female can hatch (pregnancy time)
the problem that when I make gestaton 0 then + 1 they still count even after hatching.

Thanks in advance for the help and sorry for my bad English

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can one create a countdown timer in Netlogo?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4296818/how-can-one-create-a-countdown-timer-in-netlogo)

Answer (score 0):

This may not be exactly what you're asking for, but you might be able to achieve the desired result by having a turtles own variable that you use as a gestation countdown:

```
turtles-own [ gestation ]

to-report parents-here? 
     report any? turtles-here with [gender = "male"]
            and
            any? turtles-here with [gender = "female"]
end

to go
    if ticks mod 12 <= 2 [
        ask patches with [parents-here?] [
            ask one-of turtles-here with [gender = "female"] [
                set gestation 10
            ]
        ]
    ]

    ask turtles with [gestation > 0] [
        if [gestation = 1] [
            hatch 1 [ set gender one-of ["male" "female"] ]
        ]
        set gestation (gestation - 1)
    ]

    tick
end
```