# How do you set a variable to decrease by 1 each tick without dropping below zero?

Tags: netlogo

I would like to know how to write a piece of code that causes "excitation" to decrease by 1 each tick without dropping below zero in Netlogo.

So far I have come up with this:

```
set excitation - 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean like this decrement-counter with the condition, "if excitation > 0"?

```
globals [ excitation ]

if excitation > 0 [
set excitation excitation - 1
]
```

Comment: You can refer this answer also. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4296818/how-can-one-create-a-countdown-timer-in-netlogo